# Ruby beginner. Instance variable not showing

Tags: ruby, class, variables, instance

```
class Player
  def initialize (name, age, start_year)
    @name       = name.capitalize
    @age        = age
    @start_year = start_year
  end

  def playing_for
    current_year  = Time.new.strftime("%Y")
    num_of_years  = current_year - @start_year
    @num_of_years = num_of_years
  end

  def to_s
    "Hi, my name is #{@name}. I am #{@age} years old. I have been playing Ultimate for #{@num_of_years} years."
  end
end

jon = Player.new("jon", 41, 2009)
puts jon
```

When I run the above code in Terminal, it shows as:

```
Hi my name is Jon. I am 41 years old. I have been playing Ultimate for  years.
```

and doesn't show the `#{@num_of_years}`.

Clearly there's something wrong with the way I've defined `@num_of_years`, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Where are you calling `playing_for` that sets value for `@num_of_years`?

Comment: There's another error: `Time.new.strftime("%Y")` returns a string, so `current_year - @start_year` becomes `"2016" - 2009` which doesn't work (you can't subtract a number from a string). Use `Time.new.year` instead.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you!!!

Comment: @WandMaker Sorry I don't understand your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@num_of_years` ist not printed, because the variable wasn't set (uninitialized instance variables have a value of `nil` and `"#{nil}"` results in an empty string).

`@name`, `@age` and `@start_year` are all set in `initialize` which is invoked by calling `Player.new`, and `to_s` is invoked by `puts`:

```
jon = Player.new("jon", 41, 2009) # <- "new" calls Player#initialize
puts jon                          # <- "puts" calls Player#to_s
```

`@num_of_years` on the other hand is set in `playing_for` which is never called (this is what Wand Maker [wanted to say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560887/ruby-beginner-instance-variable-not-showing/37561183#comment62610042_37560887)).

You could call the method manually before calling `puts`: (remember to fix [the bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560887/ruby-beginner-instance-variable-not-showing#comment62610145_37560887) by replacing `strftime("%Y")` with `year`)

```
jon = Player.new("jon", 41, 2009)
#=> #<Player:0x007fab8a8aa448 @name="Jon", @age=41, @start_year=2009>
jon.to_s
#=> "Hi, my name is Jon. I am 41 years old. I have been playing Ultimate for  years."
jon.playing_for
#=> 7
jon.to_s
#=> "Hi, my name is Jon. I am 41 years old. I have been playing Ultimate for 7 years."

puts jon
```

Prints:

```
Hi, my name is Jon. I am 41 years old. I have been playing Ultimate for 7 years.
```

But remembering to call the method every time becomes tedious very quickly.

It's easier to set `@num_of_years` in initialize, just like the other instance variables:

```
class Player   
  def initialize (name, age, start_year)
    @name         = name.capitalize
    @age          = age
    @start_year   = start_year
    @num_of_years = Time.new.year - start_year
  end

  def to_s
    "Hi, my name is #{@name}. I am #{@age} years old. I have been playing Ultimate for #{@num_of_years} years."
  end
end

puts Player.new("jon", 41, 2009)
#=> Hi, my name is Jon. I am 41 years old. I have been playing Ultimate for 7 years.
```

Or you could define a method to calculate the difference. But you don't need another instance variable in this case, just return the value:

```
class Player
  def initialize (name, age, start_year)
    @name         = name.capitalize
    @age          = age
    @start_year   = start_year
  end

  def playing_for
    Time.new.year - @start_year
  end

  def to_s
    "Hi, my name is #{@name}. I am #{@age} years old. I have been playing Ultimate for #{playing_for} years."
  end
end

puts Player.new("jon", 41, 2009)
#=> Hi, my name is Jon. I am 41 years old. I have been playing Ultimate for 7 years.
```

Take a look at the `to_s` method. I've replaced `#{@num_of_years}` with `#{playing_for}`.